What is the Longest Life Positron Emitter Isotope?
I was asking if there is any isotope that emits positrons with a half-life of more than one year?

How about K-40 ? Half-life well into billions of years. Plenty of other examples exist as well.

@fraxinus Well I'm not a physicist but i looked it up in Wikipedia and it doesn't emit positrons it emits electrons is that right? I also found this one thulium-168 but in days not years i need positron emission to build an antimatter engine so the longer the halfe life the more I can test the design without the need to do any nuclear transmutation

K-40 emits both electrons and positrons. It does transmutate in the process - it becomes either Ca-40 or Ar-40.

@fraxinus Cool thanks btw here is the engine I'm gonna build if you are curious https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43ym6ECkG7Y&t=65s

Wikipedia suggests that K-40 decays by positron emission in only 0.001% of events

@jim Yeah I noticed that too sodium-22 90% I think this one is a better option

You may wish to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission

@GeorgeRamzi What is your actual question? The title and body contain different questions.

Making an antimatter engine sounds like a crackpot idea. So I was surprised that you show an awareness of physics in your video. On the other hand, it is odd that you seem to think that the price of antimatter is the biggest obstacle to getting $1000000$ kg of antimatter into orbit. CERN spent 30 years learning how to produce and trap antihydrogen. They work with a few thousand atoms. ALPHA experiment at CERN observes the influence of gravity on antimatter

@mmesser314 well it's not my video but I think I can make something better than the ion thruster for a simple drone with just 100 positrons i also have another idea using alpha decay as an alternative to the ion thruster but where I live I can't put my hand on anything radioactive to just start any work it's all in my brain ):

Looks like sodium-22 fits the bill.
EDIT (Dec 8, 2024): As for the question in the title of the OP, aluminum-26 is probably the longest-life positron emitter.

Thanks that's what I'm looking for
now how can I get this isotope, is it available for sale or what, I can build a homemade cyclotron but I don't know what element or isotope to shoot at

@GeorgeRamzi Industrial Na-22 sources with nominal activities of up to 370 MBq (10 mCi) are easily commercially available. However, you need a license for sources with more than 1 MBq.

@Loong thanks speaking of the license I live in Egypt and labs here don't produce this stuff and I can't import from outside because of the events that are going on here in the middle east I don't think any country will export anything radioactive even if it's not used in any guns so I'm cooked );
